# Yank across multiple lines with single line breaks

Tags: cut-copy-paste, visual-block

I can use the following to yank text inside of quotes across multiple lines, separate that text by a single new line, and be able to paste it characterwise.

`let @q = '' | *g/^/exe 'norm! "Qyi"' | call setreg('q', "\n", 'ac')`

Applied to the following:

```
"prop1": "a value",
"propertyTwo": "another value",
"prop3": "yav",
"property four": "final value"
```

results in the following text in the buffer:

```
prop1
propertyTwo
prop3
property four
```

I would like to be able to make this buffer blockwise so I can paste the text across multiple lines. However, if I change my initial command to the following (change 'ac' to 'ab')

`let @q = '' | *g/^/exe 'norm! "Qyi"' | call setreg('q', "\n", 'ab')`

I end up with extra blank lines.
The new blockwise text in the buffer:

```
prop1
propertyTwo

prop3

property four
```

How can I copy the text into a blockwise buffer but without the extra new lines?

Comment: `:%!column -t -s:`

Answer (score 0):

Since the register is being changed to blockwise appending the newlines in unnecessary and just changing the type is enough:

`let @q = '' | *g/^/exe 'norm! "Qyi"' | call setreg('q', @q, 'b')`

Removing the `a` from the `'ab'` in `setreg()` changes it to replace instead of append. Change the value to `@q` to set the value of the register to its current value.